# Spring kafka AVRO generated class not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using confluent JDBC connector to connect to a postgres database to retrieve changes and put them in a kafka topic. Now I want to consume these messages with a spring boot consumer. These messages are in AVRO format. I have the schema from the connector and generated a POJO class for it with the avro maven plugin.

But when the listener starts there are only the following error

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:194) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:112) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1598) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1210) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition ps_git_repo-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find class ps_git_repo specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord.
```

When I do not use avro to deserialise the data then I will receive data but unreadable.

In the pom.xml I have the following dependencies

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

and in the application.properties i've added the deserialiser and schema registry url.

```
    spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer = io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
    spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers = http://localhost:9092
    spring.kafka.consumer.properties.specific.avro.reader = true
    spring.kafka.consumer.properties.schema.registry.url = http://localhost:8081
```

In the build I use the avro maven plugin to generate a POJO from the schema created by the connector.

plugin in pom.xml

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>schema</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/</sourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                    <stringType>String</stringType>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I've put the following schema into the folder and generate to pojo with `mvn generate-sources`

Schema.avsc

```json
    {
      "connect.name": "ps_git_repo",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "id",
          "type": "long"
        },
        {
          "default": null,
          "name": "name",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "name": "ps_git_repo",
      "namespace": "com.company.api.kafkademo",
      "type": "record"
    }
```

I get the ps_git_repo.java class in the correct then I have this listener to retrieve the messages.

```java
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableKafka
    public class KafkaDemoApplication {
    
        @KafkaListener(groupId = "test123", topics = "ps_git_repo_test")
        public void handleMessage(ps_git_repo message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(KafkaDemoApplication.class, args);
        }
    
    }
```

The schema cannot be found.

Does anybody know what is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the `namespace` is correct?

Comment: The class is being generated in te correct packages and can be imported in the code so I assume the namespace is correct

Comment: So you created the schema yourself with that namespace? Or did you download the schema from the Registry, then add/modify the namespace? The JDBC Source connector doesn't use that namespace name, by default (not even sure it can be changed at all), and so the Avro parser thinks you're trying to use two different classes

Comment: Yes that was the problem. The "connector.name" was used as the full path. So it was indeed the namespace. It is working now. Thanks!

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks a lot, I was stuck for more than 1 hour on this, I copied the schema but forgot to update namespace.

Comment: I recently stumbled across this problem as well and just wanted to provide a possible solution for this problem that worked for me:

It is possible that the dependencies in the target folder are not correctly marked and therefore the corresponding classes are not found. In this case, simply right-click on the pom.xml file in the root directory and select Maven -> Generate Sources and Update Folders. This will mark the folders correctly and hopefully fix errors that occur when importing these generated classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deserialiser used the connect.name field instead of the namespace to find the correct class.

I've added the following lines to the config of the JDBC_connector to let the connector generate the correct namespace

```
"transforms":"AddNamespace",
"transforms.AddNamespace.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Value",
"transforms.AddNamespace.schema.name": "com.company.api.kafkademo.ps_git_repo"
```